# Copy keywords into description exif

Tags: metadata

Is there a tool that can batch edit the image's EXIF data and copy the keywords and put it into description field?

Answer (score 4):

Sure. You could easily do this with [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). Something like

```
exiftool -'imagedescription<keywords' *.jpg
```

Where `imagedescription` is the tag you want to copy into and `keywords` the tag you want to copy from. The `<` is the copy tag value operator.

Note, though, that there are a number of different standards for this kind of metadata, and you  *might* find that your keywords are actually XMP Subject tags or something else depending on what software put them there. (Exiftool can handle this too -- you'll just have to figure out exactly what the tag names you want are.)

Comment: When in doubt as to what information goes where, there are the Metadata Working Group guidelines.                                             www.metadataworkinggroup.org/pdf/mwg_guidance.pdf#35